# How to stop bash evaluating a string

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following block in a script to verify whether a mount point is tmpfs

```
if [ "$(stat -f -c '%T' $LOGDIR)" -ne 'tmpfs' ]
then
    echo "Log directory ($LOGDIR) must be tmpfs"
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem is that if the filesystem is returned as ext2/ext3 then the shell attempts to evaluate that and falls over with a division by zero.  How can I force it to be treated as a regular string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `-ne` arithmetic operator, use the string operator `!=`.

BTW, what version of `bash` are you running? I am getting `integer expression expected`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `!=` for string comparison; `-ne` is for integer comparison only. (Actually, I'm surprised it tried to do arithmetic using "ext2/ext3", as opposed to simply treating the entire string as a zero value.)